# appengine app works only with my account

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I've developed a simple AppEngine application for my Google Apps domain. Access is restricted to users in my domain, and the app is enabled in the admin console for the domain.

The authentication/authorization in the application is done using decorators, using the JSON client secrets downloaded from my API console. I've created the client secrets of type "Client ID for web applications".

My main handler, on the GET method, is as follows:

```
@decorator.oauth_aware
  def get(self):
    if decorator.has_credentials():
      .... do stuff .....
    else:
      self.response.out.write("decorator doesn't have credentials")
```

The problem is that the application works well when I'm logged in my account. For all other users in the same domain, I get the "decorator doesn't have credentials" error.

any clue on why this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was actually quite simple: the user was not logged in and, instead of presenting a login window, the app was crashing.

to present a login window we should use `@decorator.oauth_required` instead of simply `oauth_aware`, and put `login: required` in the app.yaml file